# What is the probability of at least N heads in M flips of an unfair coin?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I see many answers about getting an exact number of coin flip outcomes with a fair coin, and some about getting an exact number of coin flip outcomes with an unweighted coin (like [this one](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-probability-of-getting-at-least-N-heads-if-I-flip-a-coin-M-times)) but I am curious about a the probability of at least a number of outcomes with an unfair coin.

e.g.

If I have an unfair coin that gets tails with a probability of `P` what is the probability that I get at least `N` number of heads in `K` flips?

For instance, if my coin gets tails 60% of the time, what is the chance that I get at least 10 heads in 100 flips?

Comment: You are looking for the [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each fair/unfair coin toss is a bernoulli trial with parameter `P`, the question of is really asking for the [Cumulative distribution function of a Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function).

For instance, if we wanted to know what the chance of getting at least 10 heads in 100 flips where the probability of getting heads is 0.4 ($P(X \ge 10)$ where $X \sim Bin(100,0.4)$)

Using the formula given in the link we get a number extremely close to 1. Or use a calculator such as [this](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) to get

$P(X \ge 10) > 0.999999 $

For more info see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723170/formula-for-cumulative-binomial-probability).

A precise answer thanks to Henry in the comments

$P(X\ge 10)=1-P(X\le 9) = 1- \sum\limits_{k=0}^9{100 \choose k}0.6^k0.4^{100-k}\approx 1 - 1.256\times 10^{-26}$

Comment: More precisely, $P(X\ge 10)=1-P(X\le 9) = 1- \sum\limits_{k=0}^9{100 \choose k}0.6^k0.4^{100-k}\approx 1 - 1.256\times 10^{-26}$, so many more $9$s